# How can I make table with only one column editable and the rest untouchable using smss 2014 and vs 2015 community

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

I want to create a table that looks like the attached photo, but can only have 1 column to have input and the rest column are untouchable.

I am using SMSS 2014 in creating database and Visual Studio 2015 Community in frontend.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf7TE.jpg)

Comment: step1: create the table on db side. Step 2 Create a windows form application for data entry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. Also we ***are not a code writing service***, we help with specific issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your table into two sub-tables; one having the editable column only whereas the other one having all other columns. Join the two tables then using PK-FK relationship. Do not allow any user to edit bigger table. Make the smaller table editable and allow the relationship to cascade update (and delete).

Comment: Thank you for this. One last question. How can I make those highlighted row can only be printed those only has inputs? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly, but if you want to print only those rows that have data, you can do this using a simple SQL query. Filter your result set using `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not give anyone write access to the table.
2. Create an update stored procedure that is designed to only update that one column. This stored procedure will have elevated rights and can update the table.

The above design would prevent anyone without database owner rights of working around the limitation.